# Python : Split a word with a start and end delimiter, and keep the delimiters inside

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, split

For this example :

```
input_text = "This is a sentence. [balise]Special Word.[/balise] Another sentence here."
```

I want to split this string with **[balise]** as start delimiter & **[/balise]** as end delimiter, but
also i want to keep (if possible) the delimiters with the word between them.
I am trying to get the following output :

```
output_text = ["This is a sentence. " , "[balise]Special Word[/balise]" , "Another sentence here."]
```

I tried many ways (with regex) without sucess, and didn't found any solutions online.
How can i do this operation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `re.findall`

```
>>> re.findall(r"(?:(?!\[balise\]).)+|\[balise\].*?\[/balise\]", "This is a sentence. [balise]Special Word.[/balise] Another sentence here.")
['This is a sentence. ', '[balise]Special Word.[/balise]', ' Another sentence here.']
```

Some explanation:

- `(?!\[balise\])` means "not followed by `\[balise\]`"
- `(?:(?!\[balise\]).)+` means "any character until `\[balise\]`"
- `.*?` means "zero or more characters (`.*`) but in lazy mode"

---

Using `re.split`

```
>>> re.split(r"(\[balise\].*?\[/balise\])", "This is a sentence. [balise]Special Word.[/balise] Another sentence here.")
['This is a sentence. ', '[balise]Special Word.[/balise]', ' Another sentence here.']
```